# enc2utf8 issue with render_book() from bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I've been writing a book with bookdown for 9 months.
Everything was doing just fine until yesterday, when I got the error message:

> output file: ML_factor.knit.md
>   Error in enc2utf8(text) : argument is not a character vector

I updated all versions (RStudio & packages (rmarkdown, knitr, bookdown, htmltools)) but I'm blocked.
I've tried coming back to previous versions of the book: that does not help.
I've seen issues with this error message on the web, but no solution has worked (to date).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give us your yaml header or a little example where the error occurs?

Comment: Hi! My problem was just solved by Christophe Dervieux. My issue was in the index.Rmd. I included an header-includes with empty items. See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1728 or https://community.rstudio.com/t/enc2utf8-issue-with-render-book-from-bookdown/46701

Comment: And thank you for asking, it's so kind of you!